# NTFS-3G cannot on macOS catalina: MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 3)

Tags: mount, usb, ntfs-3g, macos

I have upgraded my macOS from High Sierra to Catalina, which, I think, causes for me to have following error. Is there any way to fix this error?

```
$ mkdir /Volumes/FOLDER
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/FOLDER -olocal -oallow_other -o auto_xattr    
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 3).
Failed to mount '/dev/disk2s1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Please note that I have followed the following [NTFS-3G guide](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G#installation).

Comment: So you're certain it's not a hardware fault, nor is the partition inconsistent, nor is it SoftRAID/FakeRAID?

Comment: External hard disk works completely fine on any windows (parallel deskops inside Catalina), or machines with macOS that has high sierra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed this [solution for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/727220/660555):

> The error you are seeing indicates the filesystem is not clean and
>   needs checked by Windows `chkdsk`. There are components to NTFS
>   filesystem (`$MFT` and `$MFTMirr` respectively in this case) which say
>   what is where on the disk. These files no longer match each other,
>   which suggests there may be some type of filesystem corruption.

On a windows machine I have used [[`chkdsk`]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk)

> `chdsk`: Checks the file system and file system metadata of a volume for
>   logical and physical errors. If used without parameters, chkdsk
>   displays only the status of the volume and does not fix any errors. If
>   used with the `/f`, `/r`, `/x`, or `/b` parameters, it fixes errors on
>   the volume.

---

First, on a Windows machine I have done: `chkdsk <volume> /f`, which takes around 2-3 hours for 2 TB external hard disk. Then, on macOS, the error I was facing was fixed, also [Microsoft NTFS for Mac by Paragon Software](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) able to recognize the external hard disk as well.